# Gentiles and Berachoth

Tags: blessing, gentiles

It seems pretty obvious that gentiles shouldn't make Berachoth on any Mitzvoth (their 7 aren't exactly ritualistic, and they were not commanded in the rest of ours). But are there any Berachoth that they may/should say? Perhaps Nehenin (foods, scents) or Shevah (praises)? Maybe Shehehiyanu on certain occasions? Maybe even a judge who presides over a case (since they are commanded to have a justice system, which he is implementing)?

Comment: `It seems pretty obvious that gentiles shouldn't make Berachoth on any Mitzvoth` So women also shouldn't bless on anything? (If I remember, that's actually how Sefardim hold)

Comment: That's not exactly right, but assuming you're generalizing, there's still a difference between Jewish women, who are part of the Kehillah that was commanded collectively ("Asher Kiddeshanu...VeTzivanu") and gentiles, who were never part of the collective that was commanded.

Comment: @ba Moreover, it's harder to say that the gentiles were 'sanctified' in getting the 7 mitzvot, unlike women who do have an element of sanctification though mitzvot.

Comment: I can answer that there are brachot they can say, but I don't know what any of them are. Does that help you?

Comment: Well JNF beat me to it. I'm still not sure which brachot are included.

Answer (score 2):

We are instructed to answer Amen after a Bracha, if it's said by a Jew. If we hear the whole Bracha from a *goy* we also answer, otherwise we don't (we're afraid he said things we don't agree with) [SA & Rma OC 215:2]

So, apparently, a *goy* can say a Bracha, and we even say Amen. (Rma says `ועונין אמן`, I'm not sure if this should be understood as an obligation or not. I tend to understand that it **is** and obligation)

Comment: As I recall, this is referring to *birkos hanehenin*, and a non-Jew should say "*Elohei Yisrael*" rather than the standard *nusach* of "*Eloheinu*". Further the rationale of "*asur l'hanos... b'li b'racha*" provided by the gemara appears to suggest that all humans must thank God prior to eating (for example). However, non-Jews might not be bound by the מטבע שטבעו חזל beyond certain standard aspects of the formatting of blessings (e.g. *shem u'malchus*). As far as a blessing being absolutely required, I question whether it would be considered actual theft to benefit without a blessing....

Comment: ...Though I see no reason why the specific *birkos ha'r'eeyah* for natural wonders would be forbidden, either. If anything, it seems to me like a praiseworthy practice. (Then again, I haven't researched it, which is why I'm not posting my own answer).

Comment: @Fred, I can't see where you're going with this.

Comment: My main comment was that a non-Jew should not use exactly the same wording (see my first sentence in comment #1). Beyond that, I was basically rambling.

Comment: @Fred, I see. That's why we need to hear him out, so that he doesn't say a different name by "mistake".

Answer (score -1):

brochos with name of God - even Jews are not allowed beyond what was instituted.

as for thanking God without getting into saying God's name - absolutely. just like any one who benefits from someone else. my $0.02

Comment: What do you mean by "even Jews are not allowed"? Jews have more prohibitions than gentiles so I don't get the kal vahomer